# '^' does not match in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am working with Regex that does not match properly:

```
Regex.Match("\u0002\u0002BURDETTE\u0002ST\u0002\u0002\u00022115\u0004^CONESTOGA MAGNET ELEM SCH^^^ ", @"\u0002([\w\s\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004/.,:&-]+)^([\w\s^/.,:&-]+)")
```

I have no problems matching separate parts of regex:

```
Regex.Match("\u0002\u0002BURDETTE\u0002ST\u0002\u0002\u00022115\u0004^CONESTOGA MAGNET ELEM SCH^^^ ", @"\u0002([\w\s\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004/.,:&-]+)")
```

Matches: `{BURDETTEST2115}`

```
Regex.Match("^CONESTOGA MAGNET ELEM SCH^^^ ", @"^([\w\s^/.,:&-]+)")
```

Matches:`{^CONESTOGA MAGNET ELEM SCH^^^ }`

Comment: Well no, because `^` has special meaning in regular expressions... See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions If you want to match the actual `^` symbol, you need to escape it...

Comment: See http://ideone.com/fBvw4u

Comment: On the regex, `^` is a metacharacter meaning beginning of string. To make it literal it has to be escaped  => `\^`